# uninitialized value usage, error while using sprintf or strcat

Tags: c++, c, printf, strcat

The piece of code given below works completely fine on my IDE. But when I submit this on [codeforces](https://codeforces.com/), I get an error pointing at the `sprintf`  line.

> Probably, the solution is executed with error 'uninitialized value usage'

I used sprintf instead of `strcat` to concatenate two arrays as suggested from a stackoverflow answer.
But it gives me the same error.

```
char a[101],b[101],c[201],d[300];
fgets(a,101,stdin);
fgets(b,101,stdin);
fgets(c,201,stdin);
// strcat(d,a);
sprintf(d, "%s%s",d,a);
```

Comment: `d` is used uninitialized.

Comment: You can't use the same string as the destination and a source in `sprintf()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use `strcat()` if you've already initialized both strings.

Since you haven't put anything into `d` yet, you don't need to concatenate to it. Just copy the contents of `a` to it with `strcpy()`.

```
strcpy(d, a);
```

Also, even if you have initialized d, you can't use

```
sprintf(d, "%s%s",d,a);
```

It's not valid to use the same string as the destination of `sprintf()` if it's also one of the source strings.

Answer (score 3):

You are writing the uninitialized variable `d` to the location `d`. That doesn't make any sense. Perhaps you meant to do `sprintf(d,"%s",a);`?

In that case you don't need to initialize `d`, but if you use `strcat` you must initialize the first item in `d` to `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized d so it probable has no '\0' character.

strcat searches for the first 0 in the array and then starts concatenting from there. If it cant find a 0 it read past the end of the array.

```
char d[300] = {0};
```

would fix it both for strcat and sprintf

Comment: But regardless of initialization, `sprintf(d, "%s%s",d,a);` simply doesn't make any sense.